# Entering values in a many-to-many relationship : NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a table called `Items` and a table called `Categories`. Between them there is a many to many relationship meaning one item can belong to many categories, and also one category can have many items in it.

Image view:
[image]

I am using NestJS with TypeORM.

My issue is entering an Item in a database and passing in it multiple categories that it belongs to in one single request. Doing the same for categories is not needed since they are already seeded in the database and there is a fixed amount of them.

Right now the "solution" is to find the category using the   `categoryID` that has been passed in the `createItemDto` and then in the createItem method add the current item to the `items`array of categories entity.

**CreateItem method in items.service.ts**

```
  async createItem(
    createItemDto: CreateItemDto,
    user: User,
    category: Category,
  ): Promise<Item> {
    const newItem = await this.itemsRepository.save({
      name: createItemDto.name,
      description: createItemDto.description,
      price: createItemDto.price,
      delivery: createItemDto.delivery,
      cancellation: createItemDto.cancellation,
      rating: createItemDto.rating,
      imageUrl: createItemDto.imageUrl,
    });

    user.items = [...user.items, newItem];
    await user.save();

    category.items = [...category.items, newItem];
    await category.save();

    return newItem;
  }
}
```

**items controller.ts**

```
@Post('/createitem')
  async createItem(@Body() createItemDto: CreateItemDto): Promise<Item> {
    const user = await this.authService.getUserById(createItemDto.userId);
    const category = await this.categoriesService.getCategoryById(
      createItemDto.categoryId,
    );
    return this.itemsService.createItem(createItemDto, user, category);
  }
```

**Item entity**

```
import { Category } from './category.entity';
import { Rent } from './rent.entity';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('item')
export class Item extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  price: number;

  @Column()
  delivery: boolean;

  @Column()
  cancellation: boolean;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  rating: number;

  @Column()
  imageUrl: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.items, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  user: User;

  @OneToOne(() => Rent, (rent) => rent.item)
  rent: Rent;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, (category) => category.items)
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[];
}
```

**Category entity**

```
import { Item } from './item.entity';
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  category: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Item, (item) => item.categories)
  items: Item[];
}
```

**Categories service**

```
import { Category } from './../entities/category.entity';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CategoriesRepository } from './categories.repository';

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(CategoriesRepository)
    private categoriesRepository: CategoriesRepository,
  ) {}

  async getCategoryById(id: number): Promise<Category> {
    return await this.categoriesRepository.findOne(id, {
      relations: ['items'],
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly?implementing the solution?

Comment: I want to handle a situation where the user (on the frontend) wants to add an item and assign multiple categories to it. I don't know how to realize that in backend code

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Youba, thank you so much. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said *add an item and assign multiple categories to it*.

First, you should edit your `createItemDto` by making `categoryId` accept an array of categories, let's call it `categoryIds`

```
@Post('/createitem')
  async createItem(@Body() createItemDto: CreateItemDto): Promise<Item> {
    const user = await this.authService.getUserById(createItemDto.userId);
    const categories = await this.categoriesService.getCategoryByIds(
      createItemDto.categoryIds); // Create a function accept array 
                               //of  ids, it'll has a query such as [1]
    return this.itemsService.createItem(createItemDto, user, categories);
  }
```

*[1] getCategoryByIds*

```
async getCategoryByIds(ids:Array<number>) {
    return await this.categoryRepository.find({ where: { id: In(ids) }});
}
```

And finally, make some changes in `createItem`

```
async createItem(
    createItemDto: CreateItemDto,
    user: User,
    categories: Array<Category>, // Make the param accept list of categories 
  ): Promise<Item> {
    const newItem = await this.itemsRepository.save({
      name: createItemDto.name,
      description: createItemDto.description,
      price: createItemDto.price,
      delivery: createItemDto.delivery,
      cancellation: createItemDto.cancellation,
      rating: createItemDto.rating,
      imageUrl: createItemDto.imageUrl,
      categories :  categories // you only need to assign categories from item side 
    });

    user.items = [...user.items, newItem];
    await user.save();

    return newItem;
  }
}
```